# How do i use machine learning algorithms in Hadoop Mapreduce program?

Tags: mapreduce, machine-learning, hadoop2

How do i use *machine learning algorithms* in *Hadoop Map-reduce* program?
I want to use classification algorithms, Decision tree, clustering algorithms.
Other than Mahout please suggest some ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own MapReduce programs and call the third party machine learning algorithms in mapper and reducer. There are several open source machine learning libraries are available like **Weka, open nlp, ctakes, mallet,uima** etc...

Another best way is use **Spark ML lib or H2O, Oryix** on top of Hadoop.

Another solution: use **PMML and JPMML** to integrate the machine learning tools like **R, Weka, SAS with Hadoop.**
You can develop the model using any one of the tools (R, SAS, Weka) and use the model in MapReduce programs with help of JPMML.